# Dll only loads correctly via LoadLibrary?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm trying to use dbghelp.dll. If I set it up in the VS2008 properties to point to the correct library and header file, and put dbghelp.dll in the same directory as the executable, one of the functions in the dll fails. If I LoadLibrary the dll, everything that function works. I've looked at the header that gets included via the VS option, and the right one is being pulled in. The correct lib is being pulled in (checked via /verbose option), and depends.exe shows the correct dll is loaded. Does anyone know why I can't get this to work? I'll probably just go with LoadLibrary, but I'm genuinely stumped on this one.

EDIT: SymfromAddr fails with an "error 87", whatever that is. If I load the dll via LoadLibrary, it works.

Comment: Please clarify what happens when "one of the functions in the dll fails".

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer, under System, it usually has more info about the problem (missing manifests & so on).

Comment: Are you using the same DBGHELP.DLL version in both cases?  Use Process Explorer (www.sysinternals.com) to see from which folder the DBGHELP.DLL is loaded in both situations.  If this is the case, check if you refer to DBGHELP.DLL in your manifest file (MYEXE.EXE.MANIFEST or the Manifest in your resource file) causing it to be loaded from the Windows Side-by-side cache (WinSxS).

Comment: Can you try to start up the app with DependencyWalker (choose Profile in the menu of DependencyWalker).  Sometimes this can give you additional information.  Btw, error 87 means "Parameter is incorrect" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229764)

Answer (score 0):

Did you linked with Dbghelp.lib via proj settings or #pragma comment(lib,"Dbghelp.lib") ?
If you do the dll will be loaded during app initialization.